# Unable to debug a gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I have developed a Gradle plugin. Since the latest upgrade of gradle, that plugin is failing, and I need to debug the plugin in order to find out what exactly is going wrong. I am, however, unable to debug the plugin.

I'm doing the following:

1. I set the following environment parameters: `GRADLE_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"`
2. I execute the build running the plugin from the commandline
3. I attach my IntelliJ debugger to the running process.

This immediately fails however with a `ClassNotFoundException` in IntelliJ: `org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain`.

The plugin should work with all gradle versions. The plugin itself has following gradle relevant dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <groupId>org.gradle</groupId>
    <artifactId>gradle-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <groupId>org.gradle</groupId>
    <artifactId>gradle-plugins</artifactId>
    <version>1.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <groupId>org.gradle</groupId>
    <artifactId>gradle-base-services</artifactId>
    <version>1.12</version>
</dependency>
```

I have tried adding following dependency as well:

```
<dependency>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <groupId>org.gradle</groupId>
    <artifactId>gradle-wrapper</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

But that doesn't make any difference.

The difficulty here is that the plugin should work with *all* Gradle versions (version 1.12 up to 4.5). That is the reason why the plugin itself depends on old versions of Gradle at compile time. Where the different versions of Gradle differ, I currently resort to reflection to achieve my goal at runtime.

While Gradle 1.12 is in the dependencies of the project, the build being debugged uses Gradle 4.5.1. However, even if I switch the gradle version of the project being debugged, the same error remains. Also, as the plugin works fine on all versions prior to 4.5, such a debug session wouldn't help alot even if I would get it working.

Any ideas on how I can get the debugger to debug the plugin?